# Convert string to file and send this image through email attachment

Tags: android

I get an image from a PHP server as a string ([this image](http://www.buzzmob.com/api/upload/buzz/12022107323422653000_Art_Nature.jpg)), and I want to send this image by e-mail as a attachment.

When I try to send e-mail, then the attachment is papers but only plain text is displaying at the receiver end. How do I send the e-mail correctly?

This is my code:

```
Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
picMessageIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
String img_source = listBuzzInfoBean.get(photo).getBuzzImage();
File downloadedPic = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), img_source + ".jpg");// Art_Nature

Log.d("++++++++++++++", img_source);
Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(downloadedPic);
picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri); //screenshotUri
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to handle this.  I have noticed that differences between Gmail/Mail apps and how they handle this intent.

Also this post seems to have a similar problem.
[Android: Intent.ACTION_SEND with EXTRA_STREAM doesn't attach any image when choosing Gmail app on htc Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206397/android-intent-action-send-with-extra-stream-doesnt-attach-any-image-when-choo)

```
public static Intent createEmailWithAttachmentIntent(String[] addresses,
        String[] ccAddresses, String subject, String contentType,
        String filename, String messageBody) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    i.setType(contentType);
    if(filename != null && !filename.equals(""))
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filename)));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageBody);

    if (ccAddresses != null && ccAddresses.length > 0)
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, ccAddresses);
    return i;
}
```