# Share photo to facebook via intent in android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to Share photo to facebook via intent from specific url.

http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg");
sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

From galllery its working fine.

But when I pass above url to intent photo not share on facebook.

Help me for this......

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get the select intent dialog? What happens when you select Facebook? Do you have the FB app installed?

Comment: but from the url photo not posted on wall

Comment: can u give example of this for share photo via intent from specific url.

Comment: Are you sure they support sharing from a remote URL? Consult documentation, etc. for FB SDK, etc.

Comment: that i don't know can u tell it's possible or not? If u tried ever...

Comment: It looks like the MIME type ("image/png") does not match the type of your URL (JPEG)... have you tried with the correct MIME type?

Comment: you have any sample code for this?

Comment: @ArvindKanjariya : you have any issue with my answer?

Comment: @ArvindKanjariya have you solved the problem, can you  post solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for posting image from web url you will do following steps :

**STEP 1:** get bitmap from URL :

see this post

[How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

for getting image bitmap from URL

**STEP 2 :**

Store Bitmap in Images.Media temporarily and after send it you can delete it

```
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), 
                            bitmapiamge, "title", null);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
emailIntent.setType("image/png");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using"));
```

and for sending bitmap to facebook wall see this post :

[Android: Intent.ACTION_SEND with EXTRA_STREAM doesn't attach any image when choosing Gmail app on htc Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206397/android-intent-action-send-with-extra-stream-doesnt-attach-any-image-when-choo)

Answer (score -1):

Code to set the background image to the relative layout from one activity to another

in the first activity see the code shown below

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(requestCode == 1011)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            image.setImageURI(data.getData());
            imageUri = data.getData();

            String filePath[] = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; //A column name which to be return
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int index = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String path = c.getString(index);//actual path of file in sa card
            c.close();

            if(path!=null)
            {
                //Bitmap bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();              
                editor.putString("image",path);//set the path of file into the SharedResources
                editor.commit();
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

code to set background image

```
 void setLayoutBackground()
{
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("style_pref", 0);
    String path = pref.getString("image",null);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),myBitmap);
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
```

Comment: I fail to see the relevance to the question